# MySQL JDBC Inserting many to many objects without adding duplicates

Tags: java, mysql, database-design

What is the best way to add many to many objects in a MySql Database but not adding duplicate entities on either side of the many-to-many connection.

For example if I would like to add books to a database of books with an many to many connection between authors and books. I don't want to add an already existing author if he or she already exists in the table of authors instead I want to find his/hers author id and make the connection to the book. What is the best way to perform this with JDBC?

Below is a more detailed explanation of the problem. I have 3 tables Book, Author and AuthorBook. The table below would represent an joint between these.

```
Book Title |      Book Author
------------------------------------
Book 1     |      Book Author 1
Book 2     |      Book Author 2
```

If I want to add another book "Book 3" that has an author that already exists in the database "Author 2". I don't want to add "Author 2" again but rather get "author 2" id and use it for the BookAuthor table.

Comment: Use a 3-table setup: `Book`, `Author`, `Book_Author` with the latter serving a s a "link" table. This setup will also handle books with multiple authors.

Comment: Small note, `Book_Author` is only necessary if a book can have multiple authors (OP's example seems to be the simple case of single-author books)

Comment: Sorry I already have 3 tables for the many to many relation. The relation itself is not the problem. The problem is when i try to add a book which have an author that already is in the author table. I don't want to add an duplicate. I want to take that authors id and use it for the BookAuthor table.

Answer (score 0):

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) describes the optimal many-many relationship table.

Note that the `PRIMARY KEY` covers both (Book and Author, in your case), so that prevents duplicates.

For simplicity, you may as well send all references through the table, rather than special-casing the single-author books.